# From a SEO perspective, is it bad to minify HTML?

Tags: html, seo

Is it generally good, bad or no difference from a SEO perspective, and Goole SERP placement, to minify your HTML i.e. remove linebreaks, empty rows, spaces etc?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions concerning SEO belong on webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hehe. No one really uses any of the other stack exchange sites anyways so the only really good place to get an answer is here. I already got an answer so go ahead and close the question if it makes you happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SEO perspective, the line-breaks, empty rows, spaces are not taken into account. It just takes some semantic elements such as images, headers, links, paragraphs, etc.

But wait, SEO ranking differs in the website speed. So, minifying html would load the site in better speed.

So, it's **really good** to minify the page.